# KStreams tmp files cleanup

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My Kstreams consumer stores some checkpoint information under `/tmp/kafka-streams/`. This folder fills up pretty fast in our case. My kstream basically consumes a 1kb message in 3second window and dedups the same based on a key. I am looking for suggestions on how to purge this data periodically so the disk doesn't fill up in terms of what files to keep vs not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use windowed aggreation, by default a retention time of 1 day is used, to allow handling out-of-order data correctly. This means, all windows of the last 24h (or actually up to 36h) are stored.

You can try to reduce the retention time to store a shorter history:

- `.aggregate(..., Materialized.as(null).withRetentionTime(...));`
- older version (pre `2.1.0`): `TimeWindows#until(...)` (or `SessionWindows#until(...)`)

Comment: This is what I was looking for.. Thank you.. Also changed the `state.dir` to a different directory with more memory.. Will update the retentionTime